# на php приходит json равный null

Tags: php, json

Пытаюсь получить данные в формате json, приходит null

```
   $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);        
        $data = $response['cards'];
        echo json_encode($data);
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
```

Сам json

```
{
"cards":[
    {
        "number_card":"17 E6 14 3C",
        "id_student":142063,
        "status":2
    }


    ]
}
```

Comment: `multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: отправляю через postman post запрос

Comment: отправляю через консоль браузера, все штатно приходит и декодируется.

Comment: как это можно сделать, не подскажете ?

Comment: открываю в ФФ ссылку. жму ф12 - Сеть. обновляю страницу. беру искомый запрос на пхп файл из полученного лога. жму "Изменить отправить снова". Меняю тип запроса на POST, вставляю в  тело данные и жму Отправить.

Comment: Посмотрите, что приходит в `file_get_contents('php://input')`, например через `var_dump()`. Если всё нормально, то смотрите `json_last_error()`